# How to change trust levels in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis, web-hosting

I keep getting the below error when I deploy my web app to an external hosting provider:

> Security Exception
>
> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not
>   allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the
>   required permission please contact your system administrator or change
>   the application's trust level in the configuration file.

After some research, I believe this is because the provider I am using does not allow for web applications to have full trust levels as the apps are on a shared server. [(I'm using Fasthosts).](https://help.fasthosts.co.uk/app/answers/detail/a_id/506/~/troubleshooting-.net-websites)

However, when I change the trust level to partial / minimal via:

```
<securityPolicy>
  <trustLevel name="Minimal" policyFile="web_minimaltrust.config"/>
</securityPolicy>
```

I now get:

> Parser Error Message: This configuration section cannot be used at
>   this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access
>   to this section using `<location allowOverride="false">` from an
>   inherited configuration file.

Meaning the provider has prevented me from changing the trust level for the application.

So my question is: If ASP.NET defaults to full trust for applications, but shared servers only allow partial and don't let you override it via the web.config file, how do I change the trust level for my application?

(I've been going around in circles with this, so I may have the complete wrong end of the stick!)

Comment: You don't need to "change the trust level for my application" - you need to stop performing operations that aren't allowed. Your hosts have decided what trust level you're running at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors indicates that IIS is configured to run on lower trust level (most probably Medium Trust level) and web applications are not allowed to override the main config file. If your web host do not allow you to override the main config you cannot use the Full trust level.

In this case, you can ask your web hosting provider if they allow you to use full trust level. If they deny you will have to configure your web application to run with medium trust level or move to web host who supports [Full Trust level hosting](http://hosting.asp.net/hosting/home).